# What's the best practice for hyphenation in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, formatting, hyphenation

I always get those annoying hyphens on almost every line no matter what I'm doing. I edit each line individually as necessary but this becomes tedious for bigger tasks.

Is there a better way to manage my copy? Are there settings I should change or default to when writing a lot of copy to prevent or decrease the amount of hyphenation?

Comment: You do know that you can (*vastly*) influence the hyphenation settings? See the [Online help](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/text-composition.html#hyphenate_text). Either that, or -- let's face it -- your lines are just too short but you *still* want pretty justified text. In that case: you can't have your cake & eat it too.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly when the task is too big and hyphenation becomes a task in itself, I will just completely turn off hyphenation, so not sure if this answers your dilemma, but it is my "best practice".

Hyphenation is many times difficult to control 100% and there are always exceptions the client needs to check, and the designer needs to fix manually, so if there's a timing situation, its better to just not think about this.

Answer (score 0):

The fewer hyphens the better. My typography teacher in school always said never have two consecutive hyphens. So, I will often turn the hyphenation slider (under Paragraph styles) to the fewest hyphens, or turn off hyphenation altogether. Also, turning on Paragraph Composer (under Justification in Paragraph style options) will result in less hyphenation. But - and this is another topic altogether - I don't like the rag this produces.